# Opening links with javascript (using echo in php)

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, echo

I am generating my page in PHP. I am trying to open a magnet link and also open another page in a new tab which updates the download count.

My code works perfectly in Firefox, but in Google Chrome it doesn't.

How can I make this work in Google Chrome:

```
<a href='' onClick='window.open(\"$Magnet\",\"_self\");window.open(\"http://website.me/download.php?download=$ID\");'> Download</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't`. What errors occur?

Comment: In Firefox the magnet link window opens and the other page opens in another tab. In Google Chrome the other tab opens and the magnet window does not appear.

Comment: This is due to a chrome security policy that keeps webpages from opening multiple popups at a single time. Try adding a delay(setTimeout) to one of popups

Comment: Can you please give me an example because I tried as best I could to add a delay, but then neither pages open after I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a return false at the end of the onclick call.

```
<a href='' onClick='window.open(\"$Magnet\",\"_self\");window.open(\"http://website.me/download.php?download=$ID\");return false;'> Download</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I had to change the order of the links around because the page link cancelled the magnet pop up, but other than that, it worked.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see that order issue, because the code snippet was not enough to understand completely. but i came across similar issue before and hope that your's might be similar :) happy that it helped.